# What is this matrix (matrix representation of derivative operator) not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I saw a question on MS about how to solve: $$(D^2+\operatorname{Id})y=4\cos{x}$$ (here: [How do you solve $(D^2+1)y=4\cos{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677979/how-do-you-solve-d21y-4-cosx#2677991))

I thought, why not be overkill and solve this using some Linear Algebra. Define the vector space $$V = \{a\sin{x} + b\cos{x} + cx\sin{x} + dx\cos{x} \ |a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R} \} $$

This is a vector space and an obvious basis is $$E = \{\cos x, \sin x, x\cos x, x\sin x\}$$

I glare over the details but the matrix representation of D wrt to E on the right and E on the left is then:

$$M(D)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &1\\ 0 & 0 &-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and so

$$M(D^2)=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 2\\0 & -1 & -2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

and $M(D^2) + I_4$ has zeros on the diagonal and is obvisouly not invertible.

But, the solution to the ODE is obviously a linear combination of my basis vectors, so I don't understand why we can't solve the problem this way (i.e. by multiplying the coordinate vector of the function on the RHS by the inverse of $M(D^2) + I_4$).

Comment: $Ax = b$ can have a solution even if $A$ is not invertible. $b$ needs to be in the space spanned by the columns of $A$.

Comment: @LutzL that's right i edited it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system $$
\pmatrix{0&0&0&2\\0&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&0&\\0&0&0&0}
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d}
=\pmatrix{4\\0\\0\\0}
$$
is solvable, even if the system matrix only has rank $2$. In fact, the degrees of freedom correspond to the parameters of the homogeneous solution.

Comment: Ah, I see! yes, a and b can take any parameter we want, and we must have c = 0, d = 2. Very nice, thank you